# Unexpected Pandas KeyError(key) when using combination of apply lambda and if else conditon

Tags: python, pandas

When applying the set of `apply`, `lambda` and `if-else` condition, the compiler return `KeyError`

> ```
> raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'ss'
> ```

May I know what cause this issue

The following is referred to reproduced the above error

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


arr=np.array([10,2,5,3,6,8,3,3,2,5,6,8,11,14,11,100,1,3,20,21])
arr=arr.reshape((1,-1))
df=pd.DataFrame(zip([4,7],[15,18],[25,40]),columns=['lb','rb','mv'])

df['ss'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.argmax(arr[0][x['lb']:x['rb']] >= 0.3 * x['mv'] ), axis=1)

df['es'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.argmax(arr[0][x['ss']:-1] < 0.3 *x['mv'] ), axis=1)

df['t']=df.apply(lambda x: 0 if x['ss']==3 else x['ss']/4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you forgot the `axis=1` in the final lambda. It makes sense it'd evaluate as KeyError because there's no *Index value == ss*. Kindly consider:

```
df['t']=df.apply(lambda x: 0 if x['ss']==3 else x['ss']/4,axis=1)
```

Rerunning on my console worked fine, hopefully it's the same for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For future reader, I notice for my actual case, I need to also enclose the statement. For example,  `df['t']=df.apply(lambda x: 0 if x['ss']==3 else (x['ss']/4),axis=1)`.

Comment: Copy pasting your code with the suggest line doesn't generate any error, but the parenthesis might help it look tidier. Feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you with the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Yaa, your suggestion is correct. I will accept this as answer